# Trouble installing django_shop_discounts

Tags: django, django-models, django-shop

I am following the Getting Started Guide from readthedocs.org [here](https://django-shop-discounts.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html) for setting up django_shop_discounts

I aim to add coupon codes to an existing django shop

But when I do `runserver` I get the following error `ImportError: No module named polymorphic_model`

I have installed Polymorhpic but still get the same error.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'pipeline',
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'south',
    'extras',
    'photos',
    'payments',
    'accounts',
    'shop',
    'discount.default_discounts',
    'cart',
    'couriers',
)
```

This is where my "discount" folder is along with other apps
[image: This is where my "discount" folder is along with other apps]

This is what is inside my "discount" folder
[image: This is what is inside my "discount" folder]

Comment: have you added `__init__.py` file ?

Comment: I am quite new to Django and still figuring it all out, would add this to my shop app?

Comment: Have you added `discount.default_discounts` app to `INSTALLED_APPS`? And if you did, after that have you run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: I have tried both `discount.default_discounts` and just `discount` in my installed apps, when I run `python manage.py migrate` I get the error : `env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/discount/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    from polymorphic.polymorphic_model import (
ImportError: No module named polymorphic_model
`

Answer (score 0):

It is likely there are errors in your Python models. or you are missing the trailing `,` after your

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'myapp',
 )
```

But to make sure can you put the models up in your question and the installed apps so we can check for you.

Comment: I have added my installed apps, I have tried both `discount.default_discounts` and `discount`. As for the models, I am not too sure what I must do as I am following the docs and have not gotten to that

Comment: what is inside your discount folder? and where is it in the folder structure? could you add a screenshot?

Comment: I have added a screen shot

Comment: and your `class polymorphic(models.Model):` Id in the `discount.models.py` ?

Comment: No it isn't but there is the import `from polymorphic.polymorphic_model import (
        PolymorphicModel,
        PolymorphicModelBase,
        )`